# ReSharper Error: "The output has reached the limit and was truncated. To view the full output use 'Show Stack Trace in a new window' action."

Tags: unit-testing, nunit, resharper, resharper-2016

When running unit tests in ReSharper, if the output is too long, it gives this error:

```
The output has reached the limit and was truncated.
To view the full output use 'Show Stack Trace in a new window' action.
```

### Update

ReSharper fixed this issue in 2016.2, see answer from @Alexander Pacha.

Answer (score 170, accepted):

It took a few minutes of hunting. Click on the icon in the task bar:

[image]

Comment: is there any way to disable this completely? (so that it shows full stack as it was doing before ) ?

Comment: @Bek Raupov I don't think so. It seems to be a feature in the latest version of ReSharper - perhaps we should lobby them to make it work properly again.

Comment: I created an issue with JetBrains, please go vote for it if you can https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-459038

Comment: Be mindful that the stack trace window does not update... so you will have to reload it on every test run!

Comment: This view is truncated at the same place in 2023.2

Answer (score 62):

Due to the reactions from this post, [JetBrains fixed this 'feature'](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-459038) and now allows the user to configure this in the ReSharper settings: `Tools > Unit Testing > Unit Test Output > Limit number of lines in output to xxx`. This fix has been made available in ReSharper 2016.2.

[image: How to configure ReSharper to not limit the number of lines in the output to 200 but a greater number]

Comment: Here in 2023.2 this option no longer exists...